# How to add polygon fork network to brownie with correct chain-id

Tags: brownie, ganache-cli

I want to add a forked network to brownie.
If i do it like this:

```
brownie networks add development polygon-main-fork-dev cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 chainid=137 fork='https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/[apikey_not_shown_here]' accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```

the added network has the chain id 1, but this is not correct for a polygon fork. Adding the chain-id like this

```
brownie networks add development polygon-main-fork-dev cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 chainid=137 fork='https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/[apikey_not_shown_here]' accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545 chainid=137
```

leads to an error

```
ValueError: Unknown field(s): chainid
```

what is the correct way to add a chain-id to a brownie network?
(The built in network polygon-main-fork has the correct chain_id so i think there must be a way to add the chain_id)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Brownie network management docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html#development-networks),the parameter is not `chainid`, it is `chain_id`.

So it's

```shell
brownie networks add development polygon-main-fork-dev cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 chain_id=137 fork='https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/[apikey_not_shown_here]' accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```